# rails via CLI not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am trying to generate a migration file using

```
rails generate migration RemovePartNumberFromProducts part_number:string
```

(as given in the example) and I am getting

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your ruby is not in /usr/local/bin.  If you are using Ubuntu's ruby it is in /usr/bin.

Comment: what is the implications of this and how would i fix it?

Comment: I'm a little curious how your rails would have gotten configured this way... but type `which ruby` in your shell.  Assuming that it is not in /usr/local/bin, you will want to type `which rails`, and replace the shebang in that file with the proper ruby (e.g. `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` would become `#!/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: that solved it. i did "cp /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby" and then rails became responsive, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a problem with how you set up Ruby. I'd recommend using RVM for this on all *NIX systems and I've written a guide on [exactly how to do that](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you). I hope it helps you.